# Why is the normal subgroup the same as the group generated by the subset?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-presentation

Suppose the group $G =\langle X\mid \Delta\rangle$ (a presentation of $G$), where $\Delta$ is a set of reduced words in $X$. We have $G = F/R$ ($F$ is the free group generated by $X$),where $R$ is the normal subgroup of $F$ generated by $\Delta$.

Then the [note](https://people.brandeis.edu/%7Eigusa/Math131b/GenRel.pdf) I read says that $R$ is actually the set of all products of conjugates of elements of $\Delta \cup\Delta^{−1}$. Why? This doesn't make sense to me.

Say $X=\{a, b, c\}, \Delta=\{a^{2}\}$, then the products of conjugates of elements of $\Delta\cup \Delta^{−1}$ are all about $a$. By definition of normal subgroup, we should have $ba^{2}b^{-1} \in R$, which is obviously not the case, since $b$ can't appear in the products of conjugates of elements of $\Delta \cup \Delta ^{−1}$.

Comment: It's a *presentation* not a representation.

Comment: You need conjugates to make it normal.  That's what a normal subgroup is:  a subgroup that is closed under external conjugations.

Comment: $ba^2b^{-1}$ is the conjugation of $a^2$ by $b$; the point of saying "conjugates of elements" is exactly to force normality.

Comment: @Randall What does the normal group generated by Δ look like? I'm quite confused about this concept.

Comment: Well, it's hard to say because it can be big and ugly.  You take all possible products from $\Delta$, along with all possible inverses (gotta have those in a group), and all products with those inverses as well, and then you throw in all conjugates to keep it normal.  It is what it is.

Comment: Please use MathJax throughout.

Comment: "Conjugates" is not conjugates using only elements of $\Delta$. Is conjugates by all elements of the group. So in your example it's not just $a^2$, it's also $ba^2b^{-1}$, $(ab)a^2(ab)^{-1}$, $(ba^2c^{-1}b)(a^{-2})(ba^2c^{-1}b)^{-1}$, etc.

Comment: @Randall I agree with your description of the normal subgroup generated by $\Delta$, except for one word, "then". I don't think you can postpone throwing in conjugates until the end of the process. You'll need to also form products of those conjugates with each other and with the elements you had already produced earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is just some terminological confusion here. The BLAH generated by $X$ means the smallest BLAH that contains $X$ (and is a meaningful notion if the notion BLAH enjoys some sensible properties). So (with BLAH = "normal subgroup"), the **normal subgroup** generated by $X$ is the smallest normal subgroup containing $X$. This is bigger in general than the smallest subgroup containing $X$. The issue flagged in the title of your question does not apply  to the document you cite, which is talking about the **normal subgroup** generated by $\Delta$ not the **subgroup** generated by $\Delta$.